# Interface how do I get any Customer?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, abstract

we have an interface with a Generic Customer (gold/silver), now lets say i stored the last created cutomer somewhere (Cache/DB/etc).

how do i create a GetCustomer method that returns the type of customer.
Should i add GetCustomer to the base class or interface or elsewhere ? and how do we use GetCustomer ?

Hope that makes sense.

```
interface ICstomerInterface<T>
{
    T MakeCustomer();
}   

public abstract class BaseCustomer<T>: ICstomerInterface<T>
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // methods
    public abstract T MakeCustomer();

}

public class Gold : BaseCustomer<Gold>
{
    public override Gold MakeCustomer()
    {
        var customer = new Gold
        {
             Type= "Gold",
             Name = "Jack"
        };
        return customer;
    }
}

public class Silver : BaseCustomer<Silver>
{
    public override Silver MakeCustomer()
    {
        var customer = new Silver();
        customer.Name = "Jones";
        customer.Type = "Silver";
        return customer;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between a Gold and a Silver customer? Is it just a status or is there more information in one customer type than another?

Comment: yes there will be additional properties in the derived classes so they are different, just trying to keep the example simple

Comment: It is very unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish here. If this is for database data, I feel like this example code is far too simplified compared to the real use case.

Comment: IMO this is over-engineered.  `BaseCustomer` doesn't need to be generic, and it shouldn't have an abstract method to make inheritors.  IMO, you're just making things harder on yourself.

Comment: Yeah sorry, all i want is the customer without worrying about the type

Comment: Do they even need to be types then though? These just seem like different customer _objects_, not _types_.

Comment: Sure might be my terminology, object is a customer yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with you design is that `MakeCustomer` is an instance method of the customers. This means, that you must create a customer to be able to call `MakeCustomer`. In other words, this design will not work!

You have two options: Either simply initialize the customers in their respective constructors, or create a customer factory. This must be a separate class (static or not).

The generic type parameter is superfluous.

```
public abstract class CustomerBase
{
    public CustomerBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public abstract string Type { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class GoldCustomer : CustomerBase
{
    public GoldCustomer(string name)
      : base(name)
    {
    }

    public override string Type => "Gold";
}

public class SilverCustomer : CustomerBase
{
    public SilverCustomer(string name)
      : base(name)
    {
    }

    public override string Type => "Silver";
}
```

The `Type` property can be a getter only property. It can be abstract in the base class to force concrete customer classes to implement it.

The name must be passed to the constructor to be able to assign different names to different customers.

See also [Abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) on Wikipedia.

---

Example:

```
var customers = new List<CustomerBase> {
    new GoldCustomer("Frank"),
    new SilverCustomer("Jack")
};

foreach (CustomerBase c in customers) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{c.Name} is {c.Type}");
}
```

Prints:

> Frank is Gold
>   Jack is Silver

See working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BiAskT

Comment: Hi, so how would I get the Type as customerBase is abstract  I cant initialise it ?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate `CustomerBase`. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an extension method to get the customer type (on a static class):

```
public static Type GetCustomerType<T>(this ICstomerInterface<T> _customer)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

All with the intention that you don't have to make redundant code each time you create a new Customer class that implements that interface.

Comment: Hi, I sure could do that, but should i have to use an extension method, trying to get best practice here

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to use the classic [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Personally for simple classes, like the one you are asking about, I would add a static method on the base class, like so:

```
public abstract class BaseCustomer<T>: ICstomerInterface<T>
{
    public static BaseCustomer<T> GetLastCustomer()
    {
        // Get from storage, the last customer.
    }
}
```

That way your Create customer method is separate from your get customer method but still accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Hi, if add a customer like gold to GetLastCutomer I get cannot implicitly convert from Gold to T ?

Comment: Ops, me bad. The return type should be `BaseCustomer<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code doesn't contain a base type that can contain all your customers, i.e. there is no strongly-typed variable that could hold either a `BaseCustomer<Gold>` or a `BaseCustomer<Silver>`. There is no type compatibility between those two at all, no more than a `Dictionary<int>` can be stored as a `Dictionary<string>` (in fact, even worse, because there isn't covariance in your object model). Given that fact, your question makes little sense, because you'll always have to declare the type parameter to store a customer somewhere, therefore there is no need to learn the type at run time.

But let's say you want a cache that works for both. You'd introduce a non-generic base interface:

```
public interface ICustomer
{ 
    Guid CustomerGuid { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseCustomer<T>: ICstomerInterface<T>, ICustomer
{
    ///etc....
```

Now you can define a cache that could hold all customers:

```
var cache = new Dictionary<Guid,ICustomer>();
var gold = new Gold();
cache.Add( gold.CustomerGuid, gold );
var silver = new Silver();
cache.Add( silver.CustomerGuid, silver );
```

Now you can retrieve any customer by its Guid:

```
var customer = cache[guid];
```

And to determine its type, just use

```
bool isGold = customer is Gold;
bool isSilver = customer is Silver;
```

Or to get a string that tells you the type:

```
string type = customer.GetType().Name;
```